# How do I UPDATE a large table in oracle pl/sql in batches to avoid running out of undospace?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a very large table (5mm records). I'm trying to obfuscate the table's VARCHAR2 columns with random alphanumerics for every record on the table. My procedure executes successfully on smaller datasets, but it will eventually be used on a remote db whose settings I can't control, so I'd like to EXECUTE the UPDATE statement in batches to avoid running out of undospace.

Is there some kind of option I can enable, or a standard way to do the update in chunks?

I'll add that there won't be any distinguishing features of the records that *haven't* been obfuscated so my one thought of using rownum in a loop won't work (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to update every row in a table, you are better off doing a Create Table As Select, then drop/truncate the original table and re-append with the new data. If you've got the partitioning option, you can create your new table as a table with a single partition and simply swap it with EXCHANGE PARTITION.

Inserts require a LOT less undo and a direct path insert with nologging (/*+APPEND*/ hint) won't generate much redo either.

With either mechanism, there would probably sill be 'forensic' evidence of the old values (eg preserved in undo or in "available" space allocated to the table due to row movement).

Comment: Don't forget to disable foreign key constraints referencing the table.

Answer (score 2):

The following is untested, but should work:

```
declare
  l_fetchsize number := 10000;
  cursor cur_getrows is
  select rowid, random_function(my_column)
    from my_table;

  type rowid_tbl_type      is table of urowid;
  type my_column_tbl_type  is table of my_table.my_column%type;

  rowid_tbl     rowid_tbl_type;
  my_column_tbl my_column_tbl_type;
begin

  open cur_getrows;
  loop
    fetch cur_getrows bulk collect  
      into rowid_tbl, my_column_tbl 
      limit l_fetchsize;
    exit when rowid_tbl.count = 0;

    forall i in rowid_tbl.first..rowid_tbl.last
      update my_table 
         set my_column = my_column_tbl(i)
       where rowid     = rowid_tbl(i);
    commit;
  end loop;
  close cur_getrows;
end;
/
```

This isn't optimally efficient -- a single update would be -- but it'll do smaller, user-tunable batches, using ROWID.

Comment: This query may still produce ORA-01555 Snapshot Too Old. Probably because of fetching between commits

Answer (score 0):

I do this by mapping the primary key to an integer (mod n), and then perform the update for each x, where 0 <= x < n.

For example, maybe you are unlucky and the primary key is a string.  You can hash it with your favorite hash function, and break it into three partitions:

```
UPDATE myTable SET a=doMyUpdate(a) WHERE MOD(ORA_HASH(ID), 3)=0
UPDATE myTable SET a=doMyUpdate(a) WHERE MOD(ORA_HASH(ID), 3)=1
UPDATE myTable SET a=doMyUpdate(a) WHERE MOD(ORA_HASH(ID), 3)=2
```

You may have more partitions, and may want to put this into a loop (with some commits).

Comment: One should use the NTILE() analytic function if one wants evently sized sets; ORA_HASH can have unpredictable values, especially when using a value that isn't a power of 2 for the number of buckets to hash into.  ORA_HASH(n, 3) can have 4 values, so your example would have missed updating about 1/4 of the data.

Comment: Adam: Please note I used "MOD(ORA_HASH(ID), 3)", not "ORA_HASH(ID, 3)".   I deliberately used MOD because the extra parameters for ORA_HASH are confusing.

Thanks for the NTILE() reference.  I am still not fully familiar with analytics.

Comment: @adam-musch: Trying to use NTILE in a WHERE gives me the error: `ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here`

Comment: @Greg, one would then have to nest the query, as one does with all analytic functions being used in where clauses.  See here - http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/15971/2

Answer (score 0):

If I had to update millions of records I would probably opt to **NOT update.**

I would more likely **create a temp table and then insert data from old table** since insert doesnt take up a lot of redo space and takes less undo.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as select <do the update "here"> from old_table;

index new_table
grant on new table
add constraints on new_table
etc on new_table

drop table old_table
rename new_table to old_table;
```

you can do that using parallel query, with nologging on most operations generating very 
little redo and no undo at all -- in a fraction of the time it would take to update the 
data.

Comment: Seems to be the same answer on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330)